# Sptingboot junit 5

Tags: java, spring-boot

This is the problem I have at hand, I don't know how to tackle.
I searched online and came to this website with the solutions provided by previous queries asked but they still don't seem to answer my question. I'm using this in vscode and not in intelliJ.

find the picture:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdjeL.png)

Comment: What is the problem you have? Don't post code as images?

Comment: Welcome! Please, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are worried about the error lines showing under imports and annotations, try to build the project with `mvn -U clean install` and then reload the maven project.

Comment: I've created a project in spring using either jUnit4 or jUnit5 vscode. The picture I sent shows the test application and I tried using the ExtendWith instead of the RunWith that is shown. Now I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: It says the junit test cannot be resolved